# WebRTC failed to display participants videos

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, webrtc

We are trying to implement multi-party webRTC using sockets.The video of participant does not display on the screen. The IP and port of stun and turn server if working absolutely fine.

Please tell me what is wrong with the code.

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
package com.jmm.brsap.multipartywebrtc

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.webrtc.*
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection.IceServer
import java.lang.Math.log
import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.HashMap

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SignalingClient.Callback {

    private lateinit var eglBaseContext: EglBase.Context
    private lateinit var peerConnectionFactory: PeerConnectionFactory
    private lateinit var localView: SurfaceViewRenderer
    private lateinit var mediaStream: MediaStream
    private lateinit var iceServers: List<IceServer>
    private lateinit var peerConnectionMap: HashMap<String, PeerConnection>
    private lateinit var remoteViews: Array<SurfaceViewRenderer>
    var remoteViewsIndex = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        peerConnectionMap = HashMap()
//        iceServers = ArrayList()
//        iceServers.add(IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer())

        iceServers = listOf(
            IceServer.builder("IP:PORT NO")
                .setUsername("Admin")
                .setPassword("password")
                .createIceServer()
        )


//        Log.e("chao", "room created:")

        println("RUNNING")
        eglBaseContext = EglBase.create().eglBaseContext

        // create PeerConnectionFactory
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(
            PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions
                .builder(this)
                .createInitializationOptions()
        )
        val options = PeerConnectionFactory.Options()
        val defaultVideoEncoderFactory = DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(eglBaseContext, true, true)
        val defaultVideoDecoderFactory = DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(eglBaseContext)
        peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setOptions(options)
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
            .createPeerConnectionFactory()
        val surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", eglBaseContext)
        // create VideoCapturer
        val videoCapturer = createCameraCapturer(true)
        val videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(
            videoCapturer!!.isScreencast
        )
        videoCapturer.initialize(
            surfaceTextureHelper,
            applicationContext,
            videoSource.capturerObserver
        )
        videoCapturer.startCapture(480, 640, 30)
        localView = findViewById(R.id.localView)
        localView.setMirror(true)
        localView.init(eglBaseContext, null)

        // create VideoTrack
        val videoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("100", videoSource)
        //        // display in localView
        videoTrack.addSink(localView)
        remoteViews = arrayOf(
            findViewById(R.id.remoteView),
            findViewById(R.id.remoteView2),
            findViewById(R.id.remoteView3)
        )
        for (remoteView in remoteViews) {
            remoteView.setMirror(false)
            remoteView.init(eglBaseContext, null)
        }
        mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("mediaStream")
        mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack)
        SignalingClient.get()?.init(this)
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun getOrCreatePeerConnection(socketId: String): PeerConnection {
        var peerConnection = peerConnectionMap[socketId]
        if (peerConnection != null) {
            return peerConnection
        }
        peerConnection =
            peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(iceServers, object : PeerConnectionAdapter(
                "PC:$socketId"
            ) {
                override fun onIceCandidate(iceCandidate: IceCandidate) {
                    super.onIceCandidate(iceCandidate)
                    SignalingClient.get()?.sendIceCandidate(iceCandidate, socketId)
                }

                override fun onAddStream(mediaStream: MediaStream) {
                    super.onAddStream(mediaStream)
                    val remoteVideoTrack = mediaStream.videoTracks[0]
                    runOnUiThread {
                        remoteVideoTrack.addSink(
                            remoteViews[remoteViewsIndex++]
                        )
                    }
                }
            })
        peerConnection!!.addStream(mediaStream)
        peerConnectionMap[socketId] = peerConnection
        return peerConnection
    }

    override fun onCreateRoom() {}
    override fun onPeerJoined(socketId: String) {
        val peerConnection = getOrCreatePeerConnection(socketId)
        peerConnection.createOffer(object : SdpAdapter("createOfferSdp:$socketId") {
            override fun onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription: SessionDescription) {
                super.onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription)
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(
                    SdpAdapter("setLocalSdp:$socketId"),
                    sessionDescription
                )
                SignalingClient.get()?.sendSessionDescription(sessionDescription, socketId)
            }
        }, MediaConstraints())
    }

    override fun onSelfJoined() {}
    override fun onPeerLeave(msg: String) {

    }


    override fun onOfferReceived(data: JSONObject) {
        runOnUiThread {
            val socketId = data.optString("from")
            val peerConnection = getOrCreatePeerConnection(socketId)
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
                SdpAdapter("setRemoteSdp:$socketId"),
                SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.OFFER, data.optString("sdp"))
            )
            peerConnection.createAnswer(object : SdpAdapter("localAnswerSdp") {
                override fun onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription: SessionDescription) {
                    super.onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription)
                    peerConnectionMap[socketId]!!
                        .setLocalDescription(SdpAdapter("setLocalSdp:$socketId"), sessionDescription)
                    SignalingClient.get()?.sendSessionDescription(sessionDescription, socketId)
                }
            }, MediaConstraints())
        }
    }

    override fun onAnswerReceived(data: JSONObject) {
        val socketId = data.optString("from")
        val peerConnection = getOrCreatePeerConnection(socketId)
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
            SdpAdapter("setRemoteSdp:$socketId"),
            SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER, data.optString("sdp"))
        )
    }

    override fun onIceCandidateReceived(data: JSONObject) {
        val socketId = data.optString("from")
        val peerConnection = getOrCreatePeerConnection(socketId)
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(
            IceCandidate(
                data.optString("id"),
                data.optInt("label"),
                data.optString("candidate")
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        SignalingClient.get()?.destroy()
    }

    private fun createCameraCapturer(isFront: Boolean): VideoCapturer? {
        val enumerator = Camera1Enumerator(false)
        val deviceNames = enumerator.deviceNames

        // First, try to find front facing camera
        for (deviceName in deviceNames) {
            if (if (isFront) enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName) else enumerator.isBackFacing(
                    deviceName
                )
            ) {
                val videoCapturer: VideoCapturer? = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null)
                if (videoCapturer != null) {
                    return videoCapturer
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

SdpAdapter

```kotlin
package com.jmm.brsap.multipartywebrtc

import android.util.Log
import org.webrtc.SdpObserver
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription


open class SdpAdapter(tag: String) : SdpObserver {
    private val tag: String = "chao $tag"
    private fun log(s: String) {
        Log.d(tag, s)
    }

    override fun onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription: SessionDescription) {
        log("onCreateSuccess $sessionDescription")
    }

    override fun onSetSuccess() {
        log("onSetSuccess ")
    }

    override fun onCreateFailure(s: String) {
        log("onCreateFailure $s")
    }

    override fun onSetFailure(s: String) {
        log("onSetFailure $s")
    }

}
```

Peer Connection Adapter

```kotlin
package com.jmm.brsap.multipartywebrtc

import android.util.Log
import org.webrtc.*
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection.*

open class PeerConnectionAdapter(tag: String) : Observer {
    private val tag: String = "chao $tag"
    private fun log(s: String) {
        Log.d(tag, s)
    }

    override fun onSignalingChange(signalingState: SignalingState) {
        log("onSignalingChange $signalingState")
    }

    override fun onIceConnectionChange(iceConnectionState: IceConnectionState) {
        log("onIceConnectionChange $iceConnectionState")
    }

    override fun onIceConnectionReceivingChange(b: Boolean) {
        log("onIceConnectionReceivingChange $b")
    }

    override fun onIceGatheringChange(iceGatheringState: IceGatheringState) {
        log("onIceGatheringChange $iceGatheringState")
    }

    override fun onIceCandidate(iceCandidate: IceCandidate) {
        log("onIceCandidate $iceCandidate")
    }

    override fun onIceCandidatesRemoved(iceCandidates: Array<IceCandidate>) {
        log("onIceCandidatesRemoved $iceCandidates")
    }

    override fun onAddStream(mediaStream: MediaStream) {
        log("onAddStream $mediaStream")
    }

    override fun onRemoveStream(mediaStream: MediaStream) {
        log("onRemoveStream $mediaStream")
    }

    override fun onDataChannel(dataChannel: DataChannel) {
        log("onDataChannel $dataChannel")
    }

    override fun onRenegotiationNeeded() {
        log("onRenegotiationNeeded ")
    }

    override fun onAddTrack(rtpReceiver: RtpReceiver, mediaStreams: Array<MediaStream>) {
        log("onAddTrack $mediaStreams")
    }

}
```

Signaling Client

```kotlin
package com.jmm.brsap.multipartywebrtc

import android.util.Log
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.webrtc.IceCandidate
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription
import java.net.URISyntaxException
import java.security.KeyManagementException
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
import java.security.cert.CertificateException
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import java.util.*
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager

class SignalingClient private constructor() {
    private lateinit var socket: Socket
    private val room = "OldPlace"
    private lateinit var callback: Callback
    private val trustAll = arrayOf<TrustManager>(
        object : X509TrustManager {
            @Throws(CertificateException::class)
            override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
            }

            @Throws(CertificateException::class)
            override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {
            }
            override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
                return arrayOf()
            }
        }
    )

    fun init(callback: Callback) {
        this.callback = callback
        try {
            val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
            sslContext.init(null, trustAll, null)
            IO.setDefaultHostnameVerifier { hostname: String?, session: SSLSession? -> true }
            IO.setDefaultSSLContext(sslContext)
            socket = IO.socket("https://IP:PORT NO")
            socket.connect()
            socket.emit("create or join", room)
            socket.on("created", Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any?>? ->
                Log.e("chao", "room created:" + socket.id())
                callback.onCreateRoom()
            })
            socket.on("full",
                Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any?>? ->
                    Log.e(
                        "chao",
                        "room full"
                    )
                })

            socket.on("join", Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any> ->
                Log.e("chao", "peer joined " + Arrays.toString(args))
                callback.onPeerJoined(args[1].toString())
            })
            socket.on("joined", Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any?>? ->
                Log.e("chao", "self joined:" + socket.id())
                callback.onSelfJoined()
            })
            socket.on("log",
                Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any?>? ->
                    Log.e(
                        "chao",
                        "log call " + Arrays.toString(args)
                    )
                })
            socket.on("bye", Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any> ->
                Log.e("chao", "bye " + args[0])
                callback.onPeerLeave(args[0] as String)
            })
            socket.on("message", Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any?> ->
                Log.e("chao", "message " + Arrays.toString(args))
                val arg = args[0]
                if (arg is String) {
                } else if (arg is JSONObject) {
                    val data = arg
                    val type = data.optString("type")
                    if ("offer" == type) {
                        callback.onOfferReceived(data)
                    } else if ("answer" == type) {
                        callback.onAnswerReceived(data)
                    } else if ("candidate" == type) {
                        callback.onIceCandidateReceived(data)
                    }
                }
            })
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: KeyManagementException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun destroy() {
        socket!!.emit("bye", socket!!.id())
        socket!!.disconnect()
        socket!!.close()
        instance = null
    }

    fun sendIceCandidate(iceCandidate: IceCandidate, to: String?) {
        val jo = JSONObject()
        try {
            jo.put("type", "candidate")
            jo.put("label", iceCandidate.sdpMLineIndex)
            jo.put("id", iceCandidate.sdpMid)
            jo.put("candidate", iceCandidate.sdp)
            jo.put("from", socket!!.id())
            jo.put("to", to)
            socket!!.emit("message", jo)
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun sendSessionDescription(sdp: SessionDescription, to: String?) {
        val jo = JSONObject()
        try {
            jo.put("type", sdp.type.canonicalForm())
            jo.put("sdp", sdp.description)
            jo.put("from", socket!!.id())
            jo.put("to", to)
            socket!!.emit("message", jo)
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    interface Callback {
        fun onCreateRoom()
        fun onPeerJoined(socketId: String)
        fun onSelfJoined()
        fun onPeerLeave(msg: String)
        fun onOfferReceived(data: JSONObject)
        fun onAnswerReceived(data: JSONObject)
        fun onIceCandidateReceived(data: JSONObject)
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: SignalingClient? = null
        fun get(): SignalingClient? {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(SignalingClient::class.java) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = SignalingClient()
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
        android:id="@+id/localView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/vline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/hline" />

    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
        android:id="@+id/remoteView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/hline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/vline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
        android:id="@+id/remoteView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/hline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/vline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
        android:id="@+id/remoteView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/vline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/hline" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/hline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```